# Set custom banner image size with wp_customize

Tags: customization, images

I've set the banner image of my site to be customizable through appearance -> customize.

I'd like to adjust the image size and crop aspect ratio of the customizer, as it's still set to a thumbnail square, 150px by 150px and the banner image turns out blurry. Is this possible?

This is the code in functions.php

```
function tyc_banner_image($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('tyc_banner_image-section', array(
        'title' => 'Banner Image'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting('tyc_banner_image-display', array(
        'default' => 'No'
    ));


    $wp_customize->add_setting('tyc_banner_image-image');

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'tyc_banner_image-control', array(
            'label' => 'Image',
            'section' => 'tyc_banner_image-section',
            'settings' => 'tyc_banner_image-image',

        )));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'tyc_banner_image');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's fairly straightforward, just a case of knowing what to search for

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager

In my tyc_banner_image function I added the last four arguments below.

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'tyc_banner_image-control', array(
            'label' => 'Image',
            'section' => 'tyc_banner_image-section',
            'settings' => 'tyc_banner_image-image',
            'flex_width'  => true,
            'flex_height' => true,
            'width'       => 1920,
            'height'      => 500,
        )));
```